# django tests: client request is an empty string instead of an WSGIRequest object

Tags: django, django-testing

I am working on a django project for which I created an app that is used in other projects. The app and the project have their own repository and folder.

I want to write tests that are specific to the app of that form:

```
from django.test import TestCase
from django.urls import reverse

class SignUpTest(TestCase):

    def test_my_signup_get2(self):
        response = self.client.get(reverse('signup'))
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
```

When I run such tests from the folder of my app, the request object generated is an empty string, which will cause the test to fail. Within the logic of the project, the `request.user` is being accessed, which does not exist on a string.

When i run the exact same tests from the project folder where this app is used, the request object is a `WSGIRequest` object and the test succeeds, as the `request.user` is present.

How can I make sure that the request is always a `WSGIRequest`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a simple issue in `settings.py`. I hadn't added the same [context processors](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/templates/api/#built-in-template-context-processors) in the app I was testing and the project that was using the app: `context_processors.request` was missing.

```
TEMPLATES = [
{
    "BACKEND": "django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates",
    "OPTIONS": {
        "context_processors": [
            # Insert your TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS here or use this
            # list if you haven't customized them:
            # ...
            "django.template.context_processors.request", # <= this was missing
            # ... 
        ],
    },
}
```

]

Answer (score 0):

The unit tests would always be run from your Project's root, be it Django manage.py method or pytest. Please see https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/testing/overview/#running-tests-1. You can have flexibility on which app's test suite or part of a test suite should be executed.

Comment: Thanks you @Syed Muhammad Dawoud Sheraz. If I write an app that is supposed to be used in other projects, I'd always like to test that app from within the app itself. In that case, the app would become the project so to speak.